# Как сделать подчеркивание только заголовка при наведении на блок?

Tags: css

Нужно сделать, чтобы при наведении мышки на блок - подчеркивался только заголовок, а текст оставался без подчеркивания.

Вот как я сделал, но в итоге подчеркиваются все слова:

```html
<style>
.css_link {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:300px;
height:500px;
background:#ccc;
}
.css_zagolovok {
margin-bottom:30px;
}
.css_link:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
display:block;
}
.css_text:hover {
text-decoration:none !important;
}
</style>
<a class="css_link" href="">
    <div class="css_zagolovok">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="css_text">Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте стиль для заголовка при наведении на его родителя -

```
.css_link:hover .css_zagolovok {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<style>
.css_link {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:300px;
height:500px;
background:#ccc;
}
.css_zagolovok {
margin-bottom:30px;
}
.css_link:hover{
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
}

.css_link:hover .css_zagolovok {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

</style>
<a class="css_link" href="">
    <div class="css_zagolovok">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="css_text">Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </div>
</a>
```